# Joing dataframes with different column names for join

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying pySpark join

```
city_df.join(regions.select("region_id"),
                                       on=[city_df.region_name ==
                          regions_df.name], how = 'inner' )
```

And getting the error that "name" is not found among city_df columns. I don't understand why, if i clearly say in city_df it should be not "name" but "region_name"

The error:

```
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) name#32 missing from type#0,region_name#1,version#6, region_id#31L in operator !Join Inner, (region_name#1 = name#32).;
!Join Inner, (region_name#1 = name#32)
```

So what am i doing wrong? How to merge correctly on column with different names?

Comment: Is it complaining `name` column from `regions_df`  ? Also, check the syntex of `join`. It should be `df1.join(df2, df1.col == df2.col, 'how')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line you're selecting just the `region_id` column.  Because of this, there is no `name` column to reference in the join.

Also, you appear to be referencing two different region dataframes in your join: `regions` and `regions_df`.  You should be referencing the same dataframe.  Something like this should work:

```py
city_df.join(
    regions_df,
    on=[city_df.region_name == regions_df.name],
    how='inner'
)
```

Then drop any unwanted columns after.